# html5 displaying � instead of the french character

Tags: mysql, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I have been beating my head off the wall trying to figure out why my french characters are show up like "cr�� notre site Web" rather than "créé notre site Web"

My Encoding is set to UTF-8, language is fr. Some other characters work fine just not the e's and a's.

For example "L’opinion de notre clientèle" shows up just fine.

MySQL is storing the data as utf8_unicode_ci. When I browse the data in MySQL it looks fine as well.

My Browser is set to utf-8 as well

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Very, very strange that è is displayed correctly but not é. Is the server-side process aware that your database is in UTF-8? For example, in PHP, you can specify the encoding using `$link->set_charset("utf8");`

Comment: It sure is:

Current character set: utf8 stdClass 
Object ( [charset] => utf8 [collation] => utf8_general_ci [dir] => [min_length] => 1 [max_length] => 3 [number] => 33 [state] => 1 [comment] => UTF-8 Unicode )

Comment: Oh... actually, setting the encoding actually worked, the script i did was setting it as well but didn't look at the page when i got the results and just checked and the question marks are gone. Thanks! Can you add that as the answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` so we can determine what was stored.   For utf8, `créé` should be `6372C3A9C3A9`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem with UTF-8 and this worked for me:

```
$link->set_charset("utf8");
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your meta tag `Content-Type` is set to UTF8?

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

HTML5

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php echo mb_convert_encoding($yourVariable, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII'); ?>
```